# Set a parent for nodes produced by SyntaxFactory

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I am using `CSharpSyntaxRewriter` to traverse the syntax tree and `SyntaxFactory` to replace some of the nodes, for the purpose of my own C#-like DSL.

When I create a new node, e.g. a `MemberAccessExpression`, I would like to assign its `Parent` to `node.Parent`, but I have no idea how to do it. The `Parent` property is only a getter, so I assume I need to place the node in the syntax tree somehow.

Calling `ReplaceNode` on the parent of the input node has no effect. I think the returned node is irrelevant for my case, since I just need to achieve that `newNode.Parent == node.Parent`. This is important in a few steps later inside of `VisitMemberAccessExpression`. Any ideas or suggestions please?

```cs
public override SyntaxNode? VisitIdentifierName(IdentifierNameSyntax node)
{
  if (node.Identifier.Text.StartsWith("@"))
  {
    var cleanName = node.Identifier.Text[1..];
    var newNode = MemberAccessExpression(
      SyntaxKind.SimpleMemberAccessExpression,
      IdentifierName("entity"),
      IdentifierName(cleanName))
    node.Parent.ReplaceNode(node, newNode); //no success, newNode.Parent still null
    //before stepping in, I need newNode.Parent == node.Parent
    return base.VisitMemberAccessExpression(newNode);
}
```

Comment: First things first: everything is immutable in Roslyn. `.ReplaceNode(....)` will return a new, modified node.

Comment: Thank you, that brought me to the right path.